# Why can't i get data from External List within my workflow?

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow, external-content-type, external-list, sharepoint-designer

Im trying to load a value (string) into my SPD 2010 workflow from an external list. I want to save that value in a workflow variable, so I lookup for that external list and set up my filter's parameters. After I run the workflow it just finishes normally with no error, but the value is always blank. I've searched the web looking for an answer but it seems to me being the only one with that problem, i found some posts talking about problems with workflows and external list but they instead than me get security errors when running the workflow.

I will appreciate any help from you. TY.

Comment: what does your workflow do? does it update any list items? In that case you could try setting a list-field to this value to see if it gets reached.

Comment: My workflow just retrieve data from that list, not trying to update any item.

Comment: I can confirm that I have the same problem and have found no good answers online.

Comment: This issue was mentioned here: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/713080-sharepoint-workflow-lookup-data-in-external-list-returns-nothing

Comment: Same issue here. Any solution? Is this actually possible? It seems that the workflow that queries the external list is finding an empty list. Since the information is outside of sharepoint, would this make sense?